# How to use boost async_write with a vector of boost const_buffers correctly?

Tags: c++, vector, boost-asio

I am having trouble to make this line here right:

```
boost::asio::async_write(serialPort, 
                         boost::asio::buffer(
                         boost::asio::buffer_cast<const void*>(vector_.front()),
                         boost::asio::buffer_size(vector_.front())))
```

`vector_` holds a number of `boost::asio::const_buffers`

```
std::vector<boost::asio::const_buffer> vector_;
```

This stuff works, but I am quite sure that there is a way more elegant way to do this, and if not, I would like to here that from someone with a bit more experience.

So, can this solution be improved? If so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
boost::asio::async_write(serialPort, make_buffer(vector_.front()) );
```

where `make_buffer` is defined as:

```
template<typename TBuffer>
boost::asio::buffer make_buffer(TBuffer & data)
{
   auto buf = boost::asio::buffer_cast<const void*>(data);
   auto size= boost::asio::buffer_size(data);
   return boost::asio::buffer(buf, size);
}
```

which is a generic function by the way.

Comment: ok, this is cleaner indeed, thanks. But basically you are doing the same thing - right? I was wondering if there is a way to directly cast `boost::asio::const_buffer` into `boost::asio::buffer` - somewhat like this: `boost::asio::buffer_cast<boost::asio::buffer>(vector_.front())` - do you know if this is possible/impossible?

Comment: @Jook: If you don't like it, then you can change the name anytime from `make_buffer` to `buffer_cast` (in your namespace) and call it.

Comment: hehe, the name is fine ;) I am just wondering, if this could be achieved through direct type-conversion rahter than using a function.

Comment: @Jook: You know `booost::asio::buffer_cast` is **also** a function. It is function template in fact. So don't think it is something like `static_cast`.

Comment: oh, ok, this clears it up then - thanks again for the quick and accurate help!

Answer (score 4):

The elegant way is to pass the buffer directly to `boost::asio::buffer`.  One of its [overloadeds](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer/overload3.html) takes a single `boost::asio::const_buffer` and returns a type that can be used in [`boost::asio::async_write`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write.html), as it meets the requirements of the  [`ConstBufferSequence`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ConstBufferSequence.html) concept.

```
boost::asio::async_write(serialPort, boost::asio::buffer(vector_.front()));
```

As a general rule, applications should never need to use [`boost::asio::buffer_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer_cast.html).